# Continuity of a function with two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Is the function 
       $f(x)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}, f(0,0)=0$ continuous? Is this function differentiable at (0,0)?

Comment: Is the function $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(x)$? Also, remember for a function of two variables, the "limit" to a point $(x_0, y_0)$ can approach along many different paths. Specifically, consider approaching $(0,0)$ along a line $y=k \, x$.

Answer (score 2):

Without using polar coordinates, note we have

$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le |y|\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,(x,y)\to (0.0)$$

Therefore the function of interest is continuous at the origin.

---

It is trivial to see that the first partials satisfy $f_1(0,0)=0$ and $f_2(0,0)=0$.

Then, to test whether $f$ is differentiable at the origin, we analyze the limit

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{h^2k}{h^2+k^2}-f_1(0,0)h-f_2(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{h^2k}{(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}} \tag 1$$

The limit in $(1)$ fails to exist since along $h=0$ the limit is $0$ while along the path $h=k$, the limit is $2^{-3/2}$.

Therefore the function of interest is not differentiable at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

**hint for continuity**

With polar coordinates the function becomes $$f (x,y)=r\sin (\theta)\cos^2 (\theta) .$$
thus
$$|f (x,y)|\leq r. $$

its limit is zero. $f $ is continuous at $(0,0) $.

Comment: What about its differentiabilty?

Comment: @FayuTola Look if partial derivatives are continuous.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Continuity of the first partials is not a necessary condition for differentiability.

Comment: @Dr.MV I did not say it was a necessary condition. it is sufficient.

Comment: So, if the partials are discontinuous, then what?  And in this case, they aren't.  Moreover, it takes a bit more effort to show this discontinuity.  So, why bother when we have a stronger test that is easier to implement?

Comment: @Dr.MV Ok Dr., in this case the definition works as well.